# Guest OS sometimes stuck for minutes, with vSphere host and NFS storage

Tags: linux, nfs, scheduling, vsphere

I have a vSphere host, assigned two storage: local and 200G NFS.
The Guest is linux with kernel3.10, 2 cores, 4GB memory, 10GB disk stored on NFS storage, filesystem is EXT4.

Network between the vSphere host and the NFS server is not stable, sometimes disconnect for few minutes. When NFS network disconnected, the Guest may stuck and can't response any commands, even if `ps` or a single `enter` can't get a new line feedback. This lasts from seconds to minutes, and throw out cpu stall message.
One of the messages is:

```
[10952.770359] INFO: rcu_preempt self-detected stall on CPU { 0}  (t=6086 jiffies g=222282 c=222281 q=1695)
[10952.770360] sending NMI to all CPUs:
[10952.770367] NMI backtrace for cpu 0
[10952.770370] CPU: 0 PID: 73 Comm: scsi_eh_0 Tainted: G           O 3.10.20-rt14+ #7
[10952.770371] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 09/30/2014
[10952.770372] task: ffff88006e762170 ti: ffff88006e7626e0 task.ti: ffff88006e7626e0
[10952.770378] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8102eb5d>]  [<ffffffff8102eb5d>] native_apic_mem_write+0xc/0xe
[10952.770379] RSP: 0000:ffff88007fc03d88  EFLAGS: 00000046
[10952.770379] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000046 RCX: 0000000000000000
[10952.770380] RDX: 0000000000000200 RSI: 0000000000000c00 RDI: 0000000000000300
[10952.770380] RBP: ffff88007fc03d88 R08: 0000000000000028 R09: 0000000000000000
[10952.770381] R10: 0000000000008f40 R11: 00000000000007a3 R12: 0000000000000002
[10952.770381] R13: 0000000000000c00 R14: 0000000000000003 R15: ffff88007fc0bc10
[10952.770382] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88007fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[10952.770383] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[10952.770384] CR2: 00007f5f995b8be0 CR3: 000000000155b000 CR4: 00000000000407f0
[10952.770386] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[10952.770388] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[10952.770389] Stack:
[10952.770390]  ffff88007fc03db8 ffffffff8102ecaa 0000000000000002 ffff88007fc0c1e0
[10952.770391]  0000000000000000 ffffffff81951f40 ffff88007fc03dc8 ffffffff8102ed13
[10952.770392]  ffff88007fc03de8 ffffffff8102ef4b 0000000000002710 ffff88007fc0c1e0
[10952.770393] Call Trace:
[10952.770395]  <IRQ> 
[10952.770396]  [<ffffffff8102ecaa>] _flat_send_IPI_mask+0x74/0x9e
[10952.770398]  [<ffffffff8102ed13>] flat_send_IPI_mask+0x11/0x13
[10952.770399]  [<ffffffff8102ef4b>] flat_send_IPI_all+0x24/0x51
[10952.770403]  [<ffffffff8102c49e>] arch_trigger_all_cpu_backtrace+0x4f/0x79
[10952.770406]  [<ffffffff810bfc67>] rcu_check_callbacks+0x1e9/0x552
[10952.770409]  [<ffffffff81059471>] update_process_times+0x86/0xae
[10952.770411]  [<ffffffff8108f9eb>] ? tick_sched_do_timer+0x2f/0x2f
[10952.770413]  [<ffffffff8108f438>] tick_sched_handle+0x4d/0x5c
[10952.770414]  [<ffffffff8108fa25>] tick_sched_timer+0x3a/0x58
[10952.770416]  [<ffffffff8106f2c4>] __run_hrtimer+0x86/0x144
[10952.770418]  [<ffffffff8106fd9c>] hrtimer_interrupt+0x119/0x20f
[10952.770422]  [<ffffffff8154d84c>] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x77/0x8a
[10952.770424]  [<ffffffff8154c6af>] apic_timer_interrupt+0x6f/0x80
[10952.770425]  <EOI> 
[10952.770427]  [<ffffffff8154adea>] ? retint_restore_args+0x13/0x13
[10952.770440]  [<ffffffff81344b62>] ? io_serial_in+0x1b/0x20
[10952.770441]  [<ffffffff813449c5>] serial_port_in+0xd/0xf
[10952.770445]  [<ffffffff81346864>] serial8250_poll+0x2c/0xec
[10952.770446]  [<ffffffff81342956>] uartdrv_console_write+0x1ec/0x284
[10952.770450]  [<ffffffff81049bb6>] call_console_drivers.constprop.21+0xcd/0x121
[10952.770452]  [<ffffffff8104a8ff>] console_unlock+0x26e/0x314
[10952.770454]  [<ffffffff8104ae04>] vprintk_emit+0x45f/0x4f4
[10952.770458]  [<ffffffff815413de>] printk+0x54/0x56
[10952.770459]  [<ffffffff815493c6>] ? preempt_schedule+0x3c/0x61
[10952.770469]  [<ffffffff813ee471>] ata_dev_printk+0x65/0x67
[10952.770470]  [<ffffffff815497a7>] ? rt_spin_lock_slowlock+0x48/0x261
[10952.770473]  [<ffffffff813f99b4>] ata_eh_report+0x18a/0x8fe
[10952.770475]  [<ffffffff8109426b>] ? lock_release+0x176/0x1c2
[10952.770477]  [<ffffffff81093e7b>] ? lock_acquire+0xb5/0x112
[10952.770478]  [<ffffffff815497a7>] ? rt_spin_lock_slowlock+0x48/0x261
[10952.770480]  [<ffffffff813f7ab4>] ? speed_down_verdict_cb+0x2b/0x3f
[10952.770481]  [<ffffffff813f8484>] ? ata_ering_map+0x3f/0x5f
[10952.770482]  [<ffffffff813f9670>] ? ata_eh_link_autopsy+0x566/0x62d
[10952.770486]  [<ffffffff813fdd4e>] ? ata_sff_dev_classify+0xcc/0xcc
[10952.770488]  [<ffffffff813fdd4e>] ? ata_sff_dev_classify+0xcc/0xcc
[10952.770489]  [<ffffffff813fc27e>] ata_do_eh+0x30/0x98
[10952.770491]  [<ffffffff81405a58>] ? pci_write_config_word+0x19/0x19
[10952.770492]  [<ffffffff813fdd4e>] ? ata_sff_dev_classify+0xcc/0xcc
[10952.770494]  [<ffffffff813fdeb2>] ? ata_sff_softreset+0x164/0x164
[10952.770495]  [<ffffffff813fe08e>] ata_sff_error_handler+0xe6/0xef
[10952.770497]  [<ffffffff813fe42f>] ata_bmdma_error_handler+0xf0/0xf7
[10952.770498]  [<ffffffff813fbe2f>] ata_scsi_port_error_handler+0x25d/0x5b5
[10952.770499]  [<ffffffff813fc225>] ata_scsi_error+0x9e/0xc7
[10952.770507]  [<ffffffff8138077d>] scsi_error_handler+0xa0/0x3e3
[10952.770511]  [<ffffffff81075f8e>] ? need_resched+0x31/0x3d
[10952.770513]  [<ffffffff815490c7>] ? __schedule+0x45d/0x4a4
[10952.770514]  [<ffffffff813806dd>] ? scsi_eh_get_sense+0xa7/0xa7
[10952.770519]  [<ffffffff8106bfc6>] kthread+0xa2/0xaa
[10952.770521]  [<ffffffff8106bf24>] ? __kthread_parkme+0x65/0x65
[10952.770523]  [<ffffffff8154b962>] ret_from_fork+0x72/0xa0
[10952.770525]  [<ffffffff8106bf24>] ? __kthread_parkme+0x65/0x65
[10952.770536] Code: 45 00 31 c0 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d c3 83 c8 ff c3 90 55 48 89 e5 57 9d 0f 1f 44 00 00 5d c3 55 89 ff 48 89 e5 89 b7 00 a0 5f ff <5d> c3 55 89 ff 8b 87 00 a0 5f ff 48 89 e5 5d c3 55 48 8b 05 23 
[10952.770537] NMI backtrace for cpu 1
[10952.770540] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Tainted: G           O 3.10.20-rt14+ #7
[10952.770540] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 09/30/2014
[10952.770541] task: ffff880076a10000 ti: ffff880076a10570 task.ti: ffff880076a10570
[10952.770550] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8103220b>]  [<ffffffff8103220b>] native_safe_halt+0x6/0x8
[10952.770551] RSP: 0000:ffff8800769fdee0  EFLAGS: 00000246
[10952.770552] RAX: 00000000ffffffed RBX: ffff880076a10570 RCX: 00000000ffffffff
[10952.770552] RDX: 0100000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffffffff810162e7
[10952.770553] RBP: ffff8800769fdee0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[10952.770554] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 000000000000b44f R12: ffff880076a10570
[10952.770554] R13: ffff880076a10570 R14: ffff880076a10570 R15: 0000000000000000
[10952.770555] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88007fd00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[10952.770556] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[10952.770556] CR2: 0000000001b6ab80 CR3: 00000000112c6000 CR4: 00000000000407f0
[10952.770560] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[10952.770561] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[10952.770562] Stack:
[10952.770563]  ffff8800769fdef0 ffffffff810162ec ffff8800769fdf00 ffffffff81016a5b
[10952.770564]  ffff8800769fdf30 ffffffff810872db 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[10952.770565]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffff8800769fdf48 ffffffff8153aca9
[10952.770566] Call Trace:
[10952.770573]  [<ffffffff810162ec>] default_idle+0x25/0x39
[10952.770577]  [<ffffffff81016a5b>] arch_cpu_idle+0x18/0x26
[10952.770580]  [<ffffffff810872db>] cpu_startup_entry+0x123/0x180
[10952.770585]  [<ffffffff8153aca9>] start_secondary+0x246/0x248
[10952.770596] Code: 48 89 e5 0f 09 5d c3 55 48 89 e5 9c 58 5d c3 55 48 89 e5 57 9d 5d c3 55 48 89 e5 fa 5d c3 55 48 89 e5 fb 5d c3 55 48 89 e5 fb f4 <5d> c3 55 48 89 e5 f4 5d c3 55 49 89 ca 49 89 d1 8b 07 48 89 e5
```

and this:

```
[10056.112139] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[10061.126051] ata1: device not ready (errno=-16), forcing hardreset
[10061.127471] ata1: soft resetting link
[10061.686537] ata1.00: configured for PIO0
[10061.687470] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[10061.688712] ata1: EH complete
[10092.060204] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[10092.061797] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE MULTIPLE
[10092.062901] ata1.00: cmd c5/00:20:f0:b4:1f/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 pio 16384 out
[10092.062901]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
```

I need the Guest responds command when NFS network disconnected, Do you have any suggestions?